# Program with Qt crashes when executed on an other computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, dll, deployment

I am facing a problem during the deployment of my Qt Program. This is a cross-platform program (Linux/Mac/Windows) and I am facing an issue when trying to deploy my Win32 version built with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

I have no problem with building and running the program on the production computer, but when I try to run it on an other computer with a similar configuration it just crashes.

### Deployment Specification

Let me be more specific with my deployment method and the error.

As usual I have added the following dll to my release executable :

- platforms (Qt folder)
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll

and the Visual Studio 2015 redistributable (x86)

### Error message

The crash message I obtain is :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x56E5D96A (Qt5Core.dll) in snapr_exe.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

When I try to debug the program on the target computer with Visual Studio 2015, I obtain the following call stack :

```
Qt5Core.dll!56e5d96a()  Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for Qt5Core.dll]   
Qt5Gui.dll!572eb949()   Unknown
snapr_exe.exe!013c4ae1()    Unknown
[External Code] 
Qt5Core.dll!56e3d964()  Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!57269edf()   Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!5725bdc5()   Unknown
snapr_exe.exe!013f453c()    Unknown
snapr_exe.exe!013c1305()    Unknown
[External Code]
```

### Other relevant information

At a previous step of the development I could generate an executable that integrated Qt5 and that would work on both computers. Since this time, I have linked the caffe deep learning library, and I have highly-customized the Qt5 user interface.

What's more, I double checked with Dependency Walker that the DLLs I included were really X86 dll.

Any help on this issue would be very appreciated.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: have you used the windeployqt command? this is an easy way to make sure most of the dependancies (from the qt side anyway) are there.

Also, have you used dependancy walker on your exe to make sure there are no other libraries missing?

Lastly, error reading 0x000000 could be a null pointer exception, are you sure that side is handled safely?

Comment: Hi Chris,

I just tried the windeployqt command which adds a few more files, but I get the same error when running the program on the other computer.
Dependency walker is not really helping since there are a lot of API-MS-WIN-XXXXXX like errors which I read are not relevant on other topics. The other dependencies seem to be fine.
Lastly, I don't know where the null pointer exception would be thrown, do you have an idea of how to get more information on this point? The whole program is working properly on my main computer, but I'll try to check the GUI's constructor.

Thank you again

Comment: So I would check depends.exe for any errors that do not begin with api-ms. Specifically look at for qt or caffe library names. 

When you debugged on the target computer, can you not just set a breakpoint at the start and walk through until it gives you an error? This will massively help you find the source. Don't worry about the call stack so much as the last line of code that it tried to execute. It might take a bit of time. Also you could try wrapping your code in a big try...catch and using boost diagnostic error messages or similar to get a better hint.

Answer (score 1):

`platforms` `Qt5Core.dll` `Qt5Gui.dll` `Qt5Widgets.dll` are definitely not enough for deployment. `depends.exe` may show you more missing direct dependencies (as proposed by Chris), but Qt also loads plugins dynamically and `depends.exe` won't show them. As far as I remember, there's at least the "imageformat" plugins folder that is also required (for png, jpg formats to work properly).

Either you can use `windeployqt` command, either you figure out what you need by yourself. To do that, I personnaly run the program from Visual Studio. Then, the "Output" window of Visual Studio will list all the dlls being loaded (linked or loaded dynamically as plugins at runtime). You'll most likely see here the ones that are related to Qt that you did not deploy.

> I have no problem with building and running the program on the production computer

Tip: rename the folder where Qt was installed/compiled on the production computer and run your program. It will most likely start failing. This is because Qt libraries look for plugins in the current path first and if not found it goes pick them from the folder it was compiled from (absolute path being saved somewhere in the binaries). That's why it almost always works perfectly on the production computer...